# Log4j2 is printing utility class line number in method reference call

Tags: java, lambda, log4j2

I have a piece of code as below,

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add("abc1");
someList.add("abc2");
someList.add("abc3");
someList.add("abc4");
someList.add("abc5");

someList.forEach(logger::debug);
someList.forEach(l -> logger.debug(l));
```

In method reference style, output is as follows -

```
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:1249] abc1
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:1249] abc2
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:1249] abc3
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:1249] abc4
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:1249] abc5
```

While, for lambda, output is expected.

```
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:36] abc1
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:36] abc2
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:36] abc3
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:36] abc4
[com.some.pkg.AppContext:36] abc5
```

Pattern is `[%logger{36}:%L]`

Also, if I use `%F`, then method reference prints `ArrayList.java` but lambda prints expected class.

I am unsure whether I am missing something or this is a bug/limitation for log4j2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from `log4j2` point, it is expected behavior. Difference is there due to the different way in which method reference and lambda expressions are executed in java.

As per log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation) -

> If one of the layouts is configured with a location-related attribute
>   like HTML locationInfo, or one of the patterns %C or %class, %F or
>   %file, %l or %location, %L or %line, %M or %method, Log4j will take a
>   snapshot of the stack, and walk the stack trace to find the location
>   information.

In simple words, `log4j` uses `stack trace` to determine location information of the log statement.

When any method like `info()`, `debug()` etc. of `AbstraceLogger` class is called, it looks for the current `stack trace` to determine the location of the caller.

In case of method reference, `stack trace` looks something like below -

[image: Method Reference Stack trace]

Notice 3rd line from top - `ArrayList` with line 1380. I think 2nd line is ignored as it is not giving valid value of file name and line number.

In case of lambda expression, `stack trace` looks like -

[image: Lambda Expressions Stack trace]

As you can see, the last caller of `debug()` method in both cases is different and hence the line number.

With your given code, I am also receiving following logs -

```
com.some.pkg.AppContext:1380
com.some.pkg.AppContext:1380
com.some.pkg.AppContext:1380
com.some.pkg.AppContext:1380
com.some.pkg.AppContext:1380
com.some.pkg.AppContext:36
com.some.pkg.AppContext:36
com.some.pkg.AppContext:36
com.some.pkg.AppContext:36
com.some.pkg.AppContext:36
```

Difference of output with `%F` pattern is also related with this explanation. With `%F` pattern, `stack trace` is used to find the filename. `Logger` does not require `stack trace` lookup.